# How to rebase all the commits?

Tags: git, version-control

How to rebase all the commits?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? I assume you've had a PC with the incorrect date but do you really *need* to fix this? Be aware that all the commits you modify in this way will be new commits, any branches based on those commits will have to be rebased to be in the right place, anyone having a clone of your repository will need to carefully handle this by recloning and optionally rebasing/copying over any modifications they have locally. Are you sure it is worth it?

Comment: I am aware of that. Luckily its a personal repo so Im fine with that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git filter-branch` with an `--env-filter` where you recalculate the `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and / or `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git rebase --onto` to rebase each branch separately (the intial commit should preserved).

Such as you have commit `A`~`H` in `master` branch, now you can remove commits `B`~`G` by the commands:

```
A---B---C---D---E----F---G---H master

git checkout master
git rebase --onto commitA commitG master
```

Then `master` branch will look like:

```
A---H master
```

You can use the same way for other branches.